# HttpURLConnection ResponseCode return 500

Tags: java, android, rest, upload, image-uploading

I am try to upload the image by REST API.When i try connect  with HttpURL then it return aways 500 response code.I also try to solve the issues by many way don'r findout the issues.MY code

```
        URL url = new URL(urlLink);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy");
        connection.setRequestProperty("DocumentId", ""+ AppConstant.DocumentId);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.cashsheet.com");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", au);
        connection.setRequestProperty("UserId", "" + AppConstant.UserId);
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.w("responseCode", "are"+responseCode);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            connection.disconnect();
            Log.w("IOException", "are"+ioe.getMessage());
            // If HTTP response code '401' is returned then try to resume
            // the expired
            // session on the reporting server by obtaining a new HTTP URL
            // Connection.
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                //throw new ClusterException(
                //      "The access to the requested resource was denied; the request may have been made without authorization credentials.");
            }
            // If response code other than '401' is returned then propagate
            // the IOException to the next level.
            else {
                //throw new ClusterException(ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

All time it rerun response code 500 and show the error on urlLink;
urlLink ="http://www.cashsheet.com/api/upload"  .
[image]

I don't able to catch what is my error :(.Please help to me how i can solve this issues.Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 500 are server-side errors. I suggest you to contact who keeps this service reporting this error.

Comment: Hello@Bruno may be you say correct.But iSO upload the image with correctly.I try to upload this by Android.Id it was server error then iOS can't able to upload the image.